# Sonoma breaking fix to preventing Preview from opening "Open" file explorer when taking screenshot

Tags: macos, screen-capture, sonoma

**Issue**

Issue when i take screenshots on my mac, with e.g. shift ⇧+command ⌘ +4. If the screenshot is the first to be opend in the Preview app, then it also opens the "Open" file explorer. Which is not required as I don't want to open any files.

[image: Screenshot example]

**Steps to reproduce**

Step 1. shift+command+4 to take a screenshot

Step 2. select area to capture

Step 3. the screenshot opens in preview, but the "Open" file explorer also opens at the same time

**History and previous solution**

I had asked this question a couple of years ago here [Prevent Preview from opening "Open" file explorer when taking screenshot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422907/prevent-preview-from-opening-open-file-explorer-when-taking-screenshot) where a solution was found.

System Settings > ICloud > ICloud Drive > Apps syncing to ICloud Drive > Deselect Preview

This however does not work in the latest Sonoma OS.

Comment: I can confirm this bug. Though I have to imagine the "bug" was actually that turning off iCloud Drive sync caused the window not to open anymore, and that Apple "fixed" it, bringing back their intended behavior of always opening the chooser. I think that they did not consider the behavior of screenshots opening in Previews, where you'd not want a file chooser. THAT is the real bug.

Comment: That might be true, maybe I will just have to find another tool to open previews in.

Comment: For me, I ended up downloading a third party app. Shottr works SUPER well and has more features than the regular screenshot app while not being confusing. I honestly find it much easier to use. I think you should try it out! (I promise I'm not affiliated, I'm just excited not to be plagued by this Previews bug anymore)

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.